# How to set up object parameter by defualt

Tags: java, object, parameters

is it possible to set up one of arguments of object as mentioned below, but make it like Class default, not separate method for each object.

Object object = new Object(a, b, c = a+b)

for ex.

```
public FootballTeams(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gamesQuant = 0;
    this.wins = 0;
    this.draws = 0;
    this.looses = 0;
    this.setPoints(this.wins,this.draws);
}
//constructor
public void setPoints(int wins, int draws) {
    this.points = this.wins*3+this.draws;
}
```

I have tried to set it up in constructor and setter, but failed, always counts only initial values.
Thank you.

Comment: if `points` is always expected to be `3*wins + draws`, then eventually better not to have it as field, but just a calculated value (e.g. `public int getPoints() { return 3 * this.wins + this.draws; }`)

Comment: @user16320675 but It will not  belong to object this way

Answer (score 0):

No. You should use constructor overloading.

```
public FootballTeams(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gamesQuant = 0;
    this.wins = 0;
    this.draws = 0;
    this.looses = 0;
    this.setPoints(this.wins,this.draws);
}


public FootballTeams(String name, int gamesQuant) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gamesQuant = gamesQuant;
    this.wins = 0;
    this.draws = 0;
    this.looses = 0;
    this.setPoints(this.wins,this.draws);
}
```

Or you can use the [builder design pattern](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/builder-design-pattern-in-java).

And eventually get something like this (fields should have default values).

```
FootballTeams footballTeams = FootballTeams.builder()
    .name("name")
    .gamesQuant(1)
    .wins(1)
    .build();
```